# How to connect cocos2d with SmartFoxServer?

Tags: ios5, cocos2d-iphone

i am supposed to work on Game Development for that i am looking for SFS (SmartFoxServer) which can be used in conjunction with Cocos2d framework, can any one please tell how i have to connect to the SFS.

Answer (score 0):

There is an iPhone API for SmartFox server. The rest is up to you. [Here](http://www.smartfoxserver.com/download/sfs2x#p=examples) you can download some iOS samples and [here](http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/ExamplesIOS/introduction) are the explanations.